# Laravel Nova Tool - Send Metadata to Vue

Tags: laravel-nova

I'm creating a [Tool](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0/customization/tools.html#tools) for [Laravel Nova](https://nova.laravel.com/) 2.0

In my `Tool` I want to send a list of stuff to the Vue component:

in the PHP `src` for my tool I have a function that generates the "meta", as suggested in the documentation [here](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0/customization/resource-tools.html#defining-tools):

```
public function stuff() {

    $stuff = [];

    ... 

    return $this->withMeta(['stuff' => $stuff]);
}
```

In my `NovaServiceProvider.php` I instantiate the tool and call the meta function. i.e.

```
public function tools()
{
    return [
        (new Tool())->stuff(),
    ];
}
```

However, nothing is passed to the Tool.vue component, (*I have spent sometime inspecting it!*) i.e.:

```
mounted() {
    console.log(this.stuff); // undefined 
},
```

Issue is discussed here: https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/761, however note that I am using a `Tool` and not a `ResourceTool`, or a `Card`.

Is this a bug with Tools, or something I'm doing wrong? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried creating a custom tool yet, but for the custom field you can get the metadata using:

```
mounted() {
    console.log(this.field.stuff);
},
```

if you're having troubles with similar stuff, i suggest printing the content of the class in the console in a json format, it makes it easier for you to troubleshoot the problem

```
mounted() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this));
},
```

Although i don't think this is the problem can you try modifying your stuff() function to:

```
public function stuff()
{
    $stuff = [];
    $this->withMeta(['stuff' => $stuff]);
    return $this;
}
```